# ¿Cómo guardar la cantidad de producto vendido?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

- Sales
- products_sales
- Products

Entre la primera y la tercera tabla existe una relación muchos a muchos, donde necesito guardar la cantidad de producto que se vendió durante esa venta.

¿Dónde debería almacenar dicho valor calculado?

[image: Relaciones]

Comment: @BetaM esta es una pregunta mas relacionada a la teoria de normalizacion de base de datos y se puede responder con teoria asi como se han respondido otras preguntas de SO, de todas formas si tienes una idea para mejorar la pregunta la edito porque no se me ocurre que mejorar.

Answer (score 0):

Pues donde indicas en la pregunta: en `products_sales`:

```
ALTER TABLE products_sales
  ADD quantity FLOAT,
  ADD price FLOAT;
```

No serían valores calculados, pues en ninguna otra tabla tienes la cantidad vendida y el precio de venta al que ha sido servido ese artículo en ese pedido en concreto.